# Are there any value type collection in C#?

Tags: c#

Are there any collections with value type semantics in C#? So that set1 equals set2 if they contain the same structs/primitives? Maybe in the same order.

Comment: Value types and equality semantics are not directly related - this question is unclear. (Also, see [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx).)

Comment: Tuples and possibly anonymous objects are your closest bets. Though, you typically cannot enumerate over the properties of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HashSet is pretty close, but `==` doesn't compare the values in the collections.  `SetEquals` will return true if they contain the same values.  However, the order doesn't factor in.  You can use `SequenceEqual` if order is important.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     HashSet<int> set1 = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
     HashSet<int> set2 = new HashSet<int> { 2, 1, 3 };
     HashSet<int> set3 = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
     Console.WriteLine(set1.SetEquals(set2));          // True
     Console.WriteLine(set1.SequenceEqual<int>(set2)); // False
     Console.WriteLine(set1.SequenceEqual<int>(set3)); // True
  }
```